# CSS Keyframe animation transition without losing current color

Tags: css, css-animations

I am facing a challenge to make a dynamic 'hinting' system. I would like to make an element blink using only CSS. Not sure if it even possible. *Normally you should define the begin and end color of your animation* **(update: This is not true.)**, but because I would like to let it work on multiple background colours this isn't an option.

I have tried a number of options and Google queries (inherit, currentColor etc.) but all it does is go from white/transparent to #ef9633.

Anyone got some options I could try?

**Code:**

```
@keyframes nk-hint {
    0% { background-color: #XXX; }
    50% { background-color: #ef9633; }
    100% { background-color: #XXX; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes nk-hint {
    0% { background-color: #XXX; }
    50% { background-color: #ef9633; }
    100% { background-color: #XXX; }
}
```

Thanks allot already!

Comment: Hello, do I understand correctly that in short you want to make a blinking reminder somewhere on the page, that should catch the user's attention ? Is this the main and only function of this element? :)

Comment: if I understood it correctly, if you start with "red" you want to go over all different colors and come back to "red" ? You can help us all by creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Correct if the element is Red, it should blink to #ef9633 and back to red. If the element is Blue it should blink to #ef9633 and back to Blue.

Comment: @wick3d yes, the main purpose is to catch the users attention to that element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought. You can just remove the 0% and 100% and it works fine on all major browser. Still need to test this on iOS and IE.

It's safe to say you don't need to set a begin and/or end colour.

```
@keyframes nk-hint {
    50% { background-color: #ef9633; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes nk-hint {
    50% { background-color: #ef9633; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`animation-fill-mode` can do what you want, unless you need to support IE < 9. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

If you need IE 9 support, then I believe you're stuck with Javascript for the animation unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, you could make the changes as shown below.

```
.your-selector {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation: nk-hint 3s;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: nk-hint 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes nk-hint {
    0% {background-color: #XXX;}
    50% {background-color: #ef9633;}
    100% {background-color: #XXX;}
}

@keyframes nk-hint {
    0% {background-color: #XXX;}
    50% {background-color: #ef9633;}
    100% {background-color: #XXX;}
}
```

The keyframes will remain the same.